# Get a LED to fade out

Tags: led, pwm

I want to light an LED in a sketch and then have it fade out.
I tried to use analogWrite and have it decrease from a value of 255 to 0 using a for() loop, but I can't seem to get it to work.
Using digitalWrite I can turn it on and off but cant get it to fade out.
Can anyone help please.

```
const int ledPin1 = 2;
const int ledPin2 = 3;
const int ledPin3 = 9;
int j = 0;

void setup() {
    pinMode(ledPin1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledPin2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledPin3, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    j = 255;
    delay(1000);
    if (j >= 5);
    {
        analogWrite(ledPin3,j);
        delay(10);
        j = j - 5;
    }
    delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Please show what code you have, along with your wiring. There is an example in the IDE that fades an LED. Did you get that to work?

Comment: Yes I did get that sketch to work. I am using pin 9

Comment: So please show us your code and better define "can't seem to get it to work".

Comment: What sketch did you get to work?

Comment: Yes my complaint is a bit vague. The LED comes on and stays on. It is in my code. I am missing what I doing wrong. Some sort of mental block. Wiring is just a LED and resistor from pin 9 to gnd.

Answer (score 2):

Not all output pins are able to perform PWM ("AnalogWrite").

> On most Arduino boards (those with the ATmega168 or ATmega328), this function works on pins 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, and 11. On the Arduino Mega, it works on pins 2 - 13 and 44 - 46. Older Arduino boards with an ATmega8 only support analogWrite() on pins 9, 10, and 11.

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AnalogWrite

Note that the PWM-enabled ports are marked by a "~" on the board.

If you try analogWrite, e.g., on port 4, you'll get your observed switch behaviour.

Comment: I am using pin 9

Comment: Well - if that's not the problem, I'm totally with @Majenko. Post code, wiring and tell us what boards you are using.

Comment: const int ledPin1 = 2;
const int ledPin2 = 3;
const int ledPin3 = 9;
int j = 0;
void setup() {
 pinMode(ledPin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin3, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {
  j = 255;
 delay(1000);
 if (j >= 5);{ analogWrite(ledPin3,j);
 delay(10);
 j = j - 5;
 }
 delay(1000);
}

Comment: New at this so my posts may be a mess. I am using an UNO.

Answer (score 2):

Problems noted in comments:

```
void loop() {
    j = 255;             // Resets j EVERYTIME
    delay(1000);
    if (j >= 5);         // Semi-colon here makes this a null statement
    {
        analogWrite(ledPin3,j);  // j is always 255 (see line 1)
        delay(10);
        j = j - 5;       // No effect as j is reset in line 1
    }
    delay(1000);
}
```

Here's a simple fix:

```
int j = 255;   // Start at 255

void loop() {
    analogWrite(ledPin3, j);   // Set the brightness
    delay(10);
    j -= 5;
    if (j <= 0) j = 255;       // Reset j?
}
```

Comment: of course. Thank you very much. Works like a charm. I must be getting old.

Comment: How about we double what we are paying you.